# python- sqlite3.OperationalError: near "<": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using python 3.6. When I try to implement this, at line: cursor=conn.execute(cmd)
it raises an error as title, can any one help me? Thank you a lot.
Edit: I have found the solution by just editing str(id) to str(Id)

```
def getProfile(id):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("FaceBase.db")
    cmd="SELECT * FROM People WHERE ID=" +str(id)
    cursor=conn.execute(cmd)
    profile=None
    for row in cursor:
       profile=row
    conn.close()
    return profile
```

Comment: Why don't you print out `cmd`. Maybe `id` is not exactly what you think it is.

Comment: Unrelated comment to the subject of the question, but make sure you don't pass any sql injection into the "id" string.

Comment: How should I fixed? This is a face recognition program that runs based on my input ID

Answer (score 0):

The error of your query is that you don't include the quotation marks inside the cmd which are needed if your argument is a string. It should have been like this:

```
cmd="SELECT * FROM People WHERE ID='{}'".format(str(id))
```

As @Aaron_ab mentioned on the comment. You should never use SQL queries like this because a malicious user can do SQL Injection. For example, if he puts as an ID `1' OR 1=1 /*` it will return all the rows of the table.

Always, try to use prepared statements that don't allow users to forge their own SQL statement. An example:

```
cmd="SELECT * FROM People WHERE ID=%s"
curs.execute(cmd, (str(id),))
```